# Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the database does not ex

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I`m trying to extend my UserIdentity, using code first migration(EF 6.0.0.0). Actually it is my first try of Code First Migration.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string NameOfUser { get; set; }
}
```

**Add-Migration "NameOfUser"**   - OK
**Update-Database**    - OK

Field in db created and marked as "allow NULL"

But when i using any action in AccountController my app throw the Error

> Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.

How can i resolve this prob?

Comment: Are you using the same SQL connection string to run the migration and access the database?  Try logging into SQL Management Studio with the same credentials and see if you are able to view the tables.